# Complex measure integral vanishes

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I have a complex measure $\mu$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ with $\mu((-\pi,\pi))=0$ and a continuous function $g$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ with the property $\hat g(k)=0$ for $k=-1,-2,\dots$ (Fourier coefficients w.r.t $\lambda$!). Now it should hold $\hat g(0)=0$ (w.r.t. $\mu$). We may additionally use that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{ikt} \,\text{d}\mu(t) = 0$ holds for $k=-1,-2,\dots$.

Kind regards,
Sebastian

**edit:** solved it on my own! I forgot to mention that $g$ is bounded. If the negative Fourier coefficients of $g$ vanish w.r.t. $\lambda$, I can integrate the series expansion of $g$ termwise and all summands vanish because of the condition on the Fourier coefficients of $\mu$.

Comment: So what is the question? And what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The question is why $\hat g(0)=0$ holds. I tried to multiply it with $e^{it}$ or take the integral over $g-1$ for a suitable one but none of my tries was helpful.